# xarray multiplication via operator * and raw loop give different results

Tags: c++, xtensor

I'm a beginner at xtensor and in the following code, I thought the variables `result` and `sum` should be equal but aren't. In this example `result == 1000` and `sum == 55000`. The two variables also hold different results if I compare operations like `xt::transpose(x)*A*x` and its raw loop implementation (where A has compatible shape with x). How should I use xtensor operations in order to get the same results of raw loops?

```
#include <stdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xbuilder.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xstrided_view.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){    
    xt::xarray<double> x = xt::ones<double>({10ul,1ul});
    xt::xarray<double> b = xt::zeros<double>({10ul,1ul});
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
        b(i-1,0) = 1000*i;
    }
    double result = (xt::transpose(b)*x)(0);
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        sum += b(i,0)*x(i,0);
    }

    std::cout << result << " " << sum << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/GMEeEzn8r (thanks to Daniel Langr in the comments)

Comment: what results do you get?

Comment: result == 1000 and sum == 55000. I've edited the question. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/GMEeEzn8r

Comment: From the docs https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scalar.html, result is a 0-D xarray. So I thought I have to access like this.

Comment: i attempted some cout-debugging, but the outcomes confused me just more: https://godbolt.org/z/Wo4zcYn3h

Comment: It seems that you are calculating the outer product, not the inner one: https://godbolt.org/z/svT3Wz8ae

Comment: `operator*` is the elementwise multiplication. The result is definitely not a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small issue in the following line:

```cpp
    double result = (xt::transpose(b)*x)(0);
```

Very understandably, you may assume that the multiplication of the vectors gives the sum over the pointwise product, because this is what mathematical expressions would do. However this is not what xtensor does. Fo xtensor, the expression is just the pointwise product of the two vectors, not including summation.

To get the correct result, change the line to

```cpp
    double result = xt::sum(xt::transpose(b)*x)();
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried some other examples (where A is nxn and x is nx1) and the mathematical equivalents would be:

A * x <=> xt::sum(A * x,{0}),
x' * A * x <=> xt::sum(xt::transpose(x) * A * x)

Is that correct?

Comment: Can you add the full code to your question? That may help. But generally, xtensor will typically assume the `*` operator to be element-wise product, not matrix or vector product. Therefore, either write the operation yourself, or better follow the discussion from https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/issues/639 and use xtensor-blas. Is that something you can consider?

Comment: I've just found out about the xtensor-blas, and chose to use the dot function in my code. I don't think the examples I gave in my last example are correct. Thank you.